# Cannot using "response.setService/.setMesage/.setData" in java maven springboot project

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, spring-boot, maven

I try to build API with springboot, when i make controller and using response.response.setService/.setMesage/.setData i get error "The method setService(String) is undefined for the type Response", please help me to solve this problem.

```
package com.example.restapi.controller;

import com.example.restapi.entity.Hardware;
import com.example.restapi.service.HardwareService;
import com.example.restapi.util.Response;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "hardware")
public class HardwareController {

    @Autowired
    HardwareService hardwareService;

    private String serviceString = "Hardware";

    ResponseEntity<Response> create (@RequestBody @Validated Hardware hardware)
    {
        String nameofCurrMethod = new Throwable()
                .getStackTrace()[0]
                .getMethodName();

        Response response = new Response();
        response.setService(this.getClass().getName() + nameofCurrMethod); <==This is error code
        response.setMessage("Berhasil Membuat Data");                      <==This is error code


        response.setData(hardwareService.create(hardware));                <==This is error code

        return  ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Show me the `Response.java` file

Comment: `package com.example.restapi.util;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

/*Generic Method*/
@Setter /*Setter*/
@Getter /*Getter*/
public class Response<T> {
    private String service;
    private String message;
    private T data;
}`

Comment: This is the code inside response.java file @roy cha

Comment: please dont post code in comments, edit your question with the code @fajarnh

Comment: Somehow lombok is not working correctly in your case. Lombok is not able to create  setter/getter for your fields. Instead of using Lombok, try with creating setter/getter of the fields explicitly in your class , i am sure that would work.